# local variable 'final_result' referenced before assignment I am making an django calculator web app and i got stuck with this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, python-requests

Currently, I am  building  a django powered  UI Caculator app and I got stuck with this error..
I can't able to debug it.
Whatever I'm to trying is not working at all.
I mean i don't why it is telling me final result referenced before it gets assgined while i have already assigned final_result and then i have reference  final_result

**Views.py**

```
 def index(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        values=request.POST['values'] 
        print(values)
        vals=re.findall(r"(\d+)",values) 
        operators=['+','x','÷','-','%']
        opr=[]
        for v in values:
            for o in operators:
                if v==o:
                    opr.append(o)
        print(opr)                      
        print(re.findall(r"(\d+)",values))
        for o in opr:
            if o=='÷':
                i=opr.index(o)
                res=float(vals[i])/float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i]=str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)
            elif o=='x':
                i=opr.index(o)
                res=float(vals[i])*float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i]=str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)
            elif o=='+':
                i=opr.index(o)
                res=float(vals[i])+float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i]=str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)
            else:
                i=opr.index(o)
                res=float(vals[i])-float(vals[i+1])
                vals.remove(vals[i+1])
                opr.remove(opr[i])
                vals[i]=str(res)
                print(vals)
                print(opr)
        if(len(opr)!=0):
            if opr[0]=='÷':
                result = float(vals[0])/float(vals[1])
            elif opr[0]=='x':
                result = float(vals[0])*float(vals[1])
            elif opr[0]=='+':
                result = float(vals[0])+float(vals[1])
            else :
                result = float(vals[0])-float(vals[1])
        final_result=result
        print(final_result)
    res=render(request,'index.html'{'result':final_result,'values':values})
    return res
```

Comment: simple. you are assigning result to final_result but, result is in if statement and in this line. result gets None value

Answer (score 0):

If `request.method` is not `"POST"`, then `final_result` isn't assigned to before it is used the the call to `render`.

Answer (score -2):

You should initialize `final_result` before

```
final_result = 0
if request.method == "POST":
```

Just as @SLDem said.

or else declare it in the function
`def index(request, final_result=0)`
This will also work.

Comment: thats exactly my answer copied mate :)

Comment: @Niketan yup that resolved my issue .Thanku

Comment: @SLDem I just wanted to give him all the options. Have I not given the first option it would have been incomplete. I should have given credit to you sorry for that. Hope you don't mind, :)